# How can I copy data from an extended partition?

Tags: permissions, transfer

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 with three partitions: swap, root and home (extended).

I want to copy my data (80GB) from the extended (`/home`) partition to an external HDD without losing my data but I am getting some errors like `permission denied`.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Easiest would be to just drag the Documents/Music/Videos/Pictures folders (if that's where your files reside) from your /home, to the external HDD.

Comment: how to do this and avoid errors? I try a copy and past but it doesn't work.

Comment: **This is not a good way to do regular backups, but it sounds like you just want a one-time copy**. Open a `Files` window showing your /home folder. Open another `Files` window showing where you want the files to go. Drag one folder at a time from one window to the other. Repeat until all folders appear on the external HDD.

Comment: `sudo cp -a /home /media/external_hdd_mountpoint` (sudo because of the permission denied errors)

Answer (score 0):

Clonezilla is an excellent software for data backup and drive cloning.

get the disk image here http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php

burn the image to CD with a disk burning software.

you will need to turn secure boot off to boot the CD.

once booted.
local drive/partition to image. will make a backup image of your device
local drive/partition to local drive/partition will clone your device to the external.

Note: if you are going to clone partition to partition, the destination partition must be created in advance and be the same size or larger than the original.